# How fix the bounds problem with openrouteservice API

Tags: reactjs, maps, coordinates

I am trying send a request with openrouteservice, when I sent the coordinates I receive a error response

I am using react with the openrouteservice-js library

```
getResponse = async () => {
try {
    const response = await Directions.calculate({
    coordinates: [[9.930808,-84.052448],[9.933302,-84.056493]],
    attributes: ['detourfactor'],
    profile: 'driving-car',
    extra_info: ['waytype', 'steepness'],
    avoidables: ['highways', 'tollways', 'ferries', 'fords'],
    instructions: true,
    instructions_format: 'text',
    preference: 'recommended',
    units: 'km',
    language: 'es',
    format: 'json'
  });
  console.log(response);
  this.setState({ response })
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e, 'error');
}
```

}

## Example map: https://maps.openrouteservice.org/directions?n1=9.933376&n2=-84.05461&n3=17&a=9.930808,-84.052448,9.933302,-84.056493&b=0&c=0&k1=en-US&k2=km

If I put the same coordinates in the example map the route is work fine, but when I sent the request I get this response error:

{
 "error": {
 "code": 2010,
 "message": "Point 0 is out of bounds: -84.052448,9.930808"
 }, "info": {
 "engine": {
 "version": "5.0.1",
 "build_date": "2019-05-24T16:27:11Z",
 },
 "timestamp": 1558719789443
 }
}

Comment: Are you using a local server? This message normally indicates that your point is out of the range of possible values for the map you have indexed. The sample map that comes when downloading the source for example only contains Heidelberg in Germany, which means you couldn't query coordinates in the US if you were using that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still active, but I'll leave this answer here for others who might have this problem...

Many Geographical APIs accept [latitude, longitude] pairs, but Open Routes Service accepts [longitude, latitude]. If you swap them, the locations will snap to completely different locations, and if they happen to be in the ocean or outside of an inhabited area (mine was in Antarctica), this error message will be returned.

As the comment on the question said, though, it's also possible to get this error message through using the wrong map on your local version of the Open Routes Service.